# CentOS 5, port 8080 won't allow traffic

Tags: centos, iptables

I'm trying to open up port 8080 on my CentOS 5, Apache 2.2.3 server. When I go to ip:8080/mydirectory - it times out. I have ran these commands thus far:

```
$ iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
$ service iptables save
$ iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
$ service iptables save
$ iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
$ service iptables save
$ service iptables restart
$ service httpd restart
```

Below is the output of my iptables

```
$ iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8080

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8080

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8080
```

I edited apache to reflect this addition:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
  ServerName dedicatedipgoeshere
</VirtualHost>
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Are you sure you have an application that listen to 8080 in the first place? Check with 'netstat -na | grep :8080` for example, or by a telnet to `localhost 8080` and see if something replies. Your default policy is ACCEPT so the additional ACCEPT policies you have added makes no difference.

Comment: Your output rule says `--dport 8080`.  It should say `--sport 8080`.  This is not the cause of the problem, however, as your policies are all ACCEPT anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `Listen 8080` to your apache config. Just put it right above the VirtualHost block.

Example:

```
Listen 8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
  ServerName dedicatedipgoeshere
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: When I restart Apache, it says this "[error] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: Could not resolve host name *.8080 -- ignoring!"

Comment: `*.8080` or `*:8080`? Must be a colon, but you have a dot in your comment. And this applies to the VirtualHost statement, the `Listen` directive is exactly as is in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to mess woth FORWARD and OUTPUT chain, only with INPUT.

```
 iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

and OUTPUT in the case if your output policy isn't ACCEPT then

```
 iptables -I OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

But if the upper is your iptables ruleset then the timeout isn't because of the firewall but maybe apache didn't listens to 8080. Because all of your chains has ACCEPT policy.

Try

```
 netstat -tpln
```

to check out whether apache is listening on 8080.

Comment: I did all of that and ran netstat -tpln, it's not showing 8080 at all. What do you think my next step is? Thank you.

Comment: You have to configure your webserver to listen on poty 8080.

Comment: By what means do you do that, iptables? Apache? Something else? Thank you for your help. Do I set up a virtual host of *:8080 on httpd.conf?

Comment: apache, see: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/bind.html

Comment: I added my addition to the httpd.conf to my post at the bottom, still no luck. I couldn't figure out how to run that 'Listen' command with your link.

Comment: You just need to find where Listen 80 is in your config files and add Listen 8080 there. Then restart apache. After that with netstat -tpln you should see apache listening on 8080.

Comment: I added the Listen 8080 and I removed my vhost, still no luck. It does show up on netstat -tpln though.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, SELinux is enabled (and blocks) by default on CentOS. I invite you to read [this wiki article](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux) for more info on SELinux (the modes in particular).

You can adjust the settings via `system-config-securitylevel-tui` in the CLI. A quick test of this solution would be to set SELinux to permissive and add the ports you wish to allow -- as shown in [this article](http://www.linuxmail.info/firewall-configuration-centos-5/). I'd only recommend to disable it if you know what you are doing, specially for a production system!